# How to pass each value from foreach loop to mysql query

Tags: php

The aim is to fetch each value(telephone number) from foreach loop and use it to query mysql database so that i can also get the name that corresponds to that number as well

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$text = $_POST['message'];
$to  = $_POST['recipients'];//this is an array  

include('mysql_connect.php');//connect to my database
mysql_select_db("my_database");

$to = explode(", ",$to);
$to = implode(" ",$to); 

if ($to != '' && $text != "") {
    $phonenumbers = explode(';', $to);
    if (!empty($phonenumbers)) {
        foreach ($phonenumbers as $phonenumber) {;

  $construct = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mobile='$phonenumber'";//this is where my problem is, $phonenumber!! 
  $check = mysql_query($construct);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
  $name = $row[recipient_name];}//My aim is to use this name in the message body

            $filename = "/send_message";//keep all messages in this file
            $handle = fopen($filename .".LOCK", "x+");
            if ($handle != false) {
                fwrite($handle, "To: $phonenumber\n");  
                $text = "$name".$_POST['message'];//Every message   should start with recipient name
                fwrite($handle, $text);
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the problem. Does $phonenumber come up empty in your program? Also you might want to filter it to prevent SQL injections and use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($phonenumbers) to see what's inside? Some remarks: dont use mysql_query, it's deprecated. Furthermore you should make sure your variables are kept outside your string, use printf or manage your quotes.

Comment: @Ynhockey i get an array when i print $phonenumber which i can't use to query the database all at once

Comment: @Tikkes thanks for advice, inside $phonenumbers is an array on telephone numbers

Comment: You also have a ';' right behind your '{' after the foreach. Remove this. That might help you somewhat too.

Comment: have you find any help is helpful to u.?

Comment: Your code is open to [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
Also keep in mind that all `mysql_*` functions in PHP have been deprecated and
so should not be used in new software. There are alternatives like
[**PDO**](http://php.net/PDO) or [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/MySQLi)

Comment: thanks dualed,noted. this is not the actual code i've used. i simplified it to make people understant what i was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$contactListString = implode("','", $phonenumbers);
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mobile IN ('$contactListString')";
```

Comment: now tell me why use "','" that will add ',' as separator and that wont work in IN CLAUSE...

Comment: Please check it my Friend, i think it has to be there.

Comment: i suggest you refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405583/using-an-in-clause-with-mysql-with-stated-values). When checking for string values in IN clause, single quotes must be there. Why dont you try to fire a query on your own. Use strings in IN clause. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Bhavik and Dipesh, besides syntax errors, the main problem was where='$phonenumber' part i replaced it with mobile IN($phonenumber). Also i've added a rand() function after filename to make the filenames unique, it was impossible to write multiple files on the same folder with the same name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN keyword in your SQL query.  So your code would look like

```
$construct = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mobile IN (";
if (!empty($phonenumbers)) {
    foreach ($phonenumbers as $phonenumber) {
      $construct = $construct + $phonenumber + ',';
    }
    //strip the trailing comma and close IN() statement
    $construct = rtrim($construct, ',') + ");";
```

That's assuming your phone numbers are stored as integers in the database.  If they're stored as strings, you'll have to surround them with quotes where you construct the $construct string.

The SQL query would look like "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mobile IN(12345,6789,28191);"

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code you dont need to add nu-necessary loop, because looping too much may slow down site performance if loops runs for more than 1000 times.
Try not to slow down your site by get rid of extra unwanted loops always use simple way to achieve result at low server damage or slow down cost..
if $phonenumbers is array then :

```
$phonenumbers = imploade(",", $phonenumbers)
```

**OR**

```
$phonenumbers = str_replace(';',',', $to);
```

**and then**

```
$construct = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mobile IN ($phonenumbers)";
```

**Final Code must be**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    $text = $_POST['message'];
    $to  = $_POST['recipients'];
    include('mysql_connect.php');
    mysql_select_db("my_database");

    $to = explode(", ",$to);
    $to = implode(" ",$to);

    if ($to != '' && $text != "")
    {
        $phonenumbers = explode(';', $to);
        $phonenumbers = implode(", ", $phonenumbers);

        if (!empty($phonenumbers))
        {

            $construct = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mobile IN ("'.$phonenumbers.'")";
            $check = mysql_query($construct);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check))
            {
                $name = $row[recipient_name];
            }
            $filename = "/send_message";
            $handle = fopen($filename .".LOCK", "x+");
            if ($handle != false)
            {
                fwrite($handle, "To: $phonenumber\n");  
                $text = "$name".$_POST['message'];
                fwrite($handle, $text);
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: he already exploding and imploding i don't know why by the way $phonnumbers is not a array because he is exploding it by ; this.

Comment: Please dont mind my Friend, but he has clearly mentioned in his comment that $phonenumbers is array. And you also need to put single quotes around $phonenumbers. I am not trying to argue with you but my only intention here is to learn. Thanks

Comment: i don't mind it bro...actually i am confuse because he already used $to = explode(", ",$to); and $to = implode(" ",$to); and then in if condition he again making that string to array...he is wrong in question because $phonenumbers is actually array itself because he is exploading it. and thats why i suggest him to str_replace ; with , and do IN in mysql isnt it.?

Comment: i have stated that $phonenumbers is array because that what clearly he has mentioned in comment. Please ask Marcus about it. Why are you asking me? hahahhah. Thanks anyways

Comment: i know you stated its array but when it first come to if condition it wasn't array...sorry